# Auto populate cells with moving down logic

Tags: excel, vba

I need auto populate cells with moving down logic. 
Logic is ->> There are 2 values, Cell "C11" = "S" and Cell "C12" = "H", and i need it fill in down till last cell not empty cell in coulmn "D11:D". Issue appears whetn number of not empty cell <=4. Error messegi is "Run-time Error 1004. Autofill Method of Range Class Failed”. Can you please support me to revright the code? Thnak you.

```
Sub automatic_data_population()
            Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C11").FormulaR1C1 = "S"
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C12").FormulaR1C1 = "H"
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C13").FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-2]C"
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C14").FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-2]C"
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C13:C14").AutoFill Destination:=Range("C13:C" & Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable to check the last row first, if its lower than your first autofill row, then don't do it:

```
Option Explicit
Sub automatic_data_population()

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Range("C11") = "S"
        .Range("C12") = "H"
        .Range("C13").FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-2]C"
        .Range("C14").FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-2]C"
        Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
        If LastRow > 14 Then _
            .Range("C13:C14").AutoFill Destination:=Range("C13:C" & LastRow)
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here for your reference.

```
Sub automatic_data_population()

Dim i as integer
Dim lastrow As Integer

With Sheets("Sheet1")
' fetch the row no of lastrow based on the data in column D
lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

' odd row ="S", even row = "H"
For i = 11 To lastrow
    If i Mod 2 Then
    .Cells(i, 3) = "S"
    Else
    .Cells(i, 3) = "H"
    End If
Next
End With

End Sub
```